# What is the problem with dictionary while using tuple as a key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created a simple dictionary in which tuples are keys

```py
a = {(1, 2): 1, (2, 3): 2}
```

These both are giving the same results:

```py
print(a[1, 2])
print(a[(1, 2)])
```

The result is `1`.

why?

Comment: What behavior are you expecting?  What do you think `a[1, 2]` should return?

Comment: 1,2 and (1,2) are both ways of writing a tuple. So you are using the same key and thus getting the same result.

Comment: @0x5453 i am confused only

Comment: You need to remember that it's not the parentheses that make a tuple - it's the comma

Comment: @OlvinRoght ya i understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1, 2` and `(1, 2)` are both tuples.  You can confirm this yourself:

```
a = 1, 2
b = (1, 2)
print(type(a))  # <class 'tuple'>
print(type(b))  # <class 'tuple'>
```

As a result, `a[1, 2]` and `a[(1, 2)]` are equivalent.

You only need parenthesis around elements of a tuple in certain contexts where the syntax could be ambiguous.  For example when passing function args: `f(1, 2)` passes two arguments to `f`, but `f((1, 2))` passes a single two-item tuple to `f`.

In all other contexts where there is no ambiguity, the parentheses around the tuple can be omitted.  Dictionary lookup is one such context.

Comment: Indexing is slightly more complicated. The commas are part of the extended slicing syntax, allowing things like `d[:, 1:, ::-1]`, where the index is not a single tuple, but rather multiple slicing constructs separated by commas. (The end result, though, is a tuple consisting of the results of each separate slice.)